# Coefficients of linear regression y=mx+c using lm() differ in magnitude from what I expect

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, coefficients

```
ddd = lm('USER ID' ~ 'CREATED ON')  
summary(ddd)
```

The slope of line in second image should be approx. (6000-0)/(2017-2016)=6000 but the slope as shown in first image is 2.204e-04. How does this make sense?

(USER ID and CREATED ON are same as no of users and time as shown in plot)

[image: please see attached output image]

[image]

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Please kindly answer one more question, I had edited the question and added one more plot, please go through it once

Comment: 1) I'm not sure where you're getting `(6000-0)` from, as it doesnt look like times 2016 or 2017 match those 2 y values. 2) you should tell us what the input looks like, for example, did you treat time as a continuous variable, or a factor?

Comment: I generated plot using this command plot(Data1$CREATED ON,Data1$USER ID, cex=0.5, xlab="Time", ylab="No.Of Users")
then abline(lm('USER ID'~'CREATED ON'),col=4) to add linear line
Do you want to me to share the data ?

Comment: The summary tells you that an increase of 1 units in `CREATED ON` results in an increase of 0.0002204 in `USER ID`. I'm guessing that `CREATED ON` is not measured in integer years.

Comment: @Simon 1) At time=2017, No.of Users~6000 or 8000 and At time=2016 No.of Users~0 (very rough values just for calculating slope), so slope must be ((6000,8000)-0)/(2017-2016) = (6000,8000) but the slope shown is in 10^-4
2) CREATED ON column is a Date Time type. class(CREATED ON) gives output "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: Review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I generated plot using `plot(Data1$'CREATED ON', Data1$'USER ID', cex = 0.5, xlab = "Time", ylab = "No.Of Users")` then `abline(lm('USER ID'~'CREATED ON', Data1), col=4)`.
>
> At time = 2017, No.of Users ~ 6000 and At time = 2016 No.of Users ~ 0 so slope must be `(6000 - 0)/(2017-2016) = 6000`, but the slope shown is in 10^-4 magnitude.
>
> `CREATED ON` column is a Date Time type. `class(CREATED ON)` gives output `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Check `as.integer(Data1$'CREATED ON')`. Date and DateTime object are integers that can be large.

---

In general, why not just extract the model matrix to see what columns are?

```
model.matrix.lm(ddd)
```

This immediately exposes the problem. Regression coefficients are computed using this model matrix.